# Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please don't mark it as duplicate first please read my question, I tried bind my function in constructor and also tried to bind in return but still i'm getting the error that "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined."When i remove bind from constructor it gave me error of updateComment.I mean to say that i tried to bind this but nothing helps.

COde:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>React Practice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/jsx">
            class Basics extends React.Component
            {
                constructor () {
                    super();
                    this.state = {editing:false};
                }
                edit () {
                    this.setState({editing:true});
                }
                save () {
                    this.setState({editing:false});
                    this.props.upComment(this.refs.newText.value, this.props.index);
                }
                remove () {
                    this.props.delComment(this.props.index);
                }
                renderNormal () {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <div className="commentText">{this.props.children}</div>
                            <button onClick={this.edit.bind(this)} className="button-primary">Edit</button>
                            <button onClick={this.remove.bind(this)} className="button-danger">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
                renderForm () {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <textarea ref='newText' defaultValue={this.props.children}></textarea>
                            <button onClick={this.save.bind(this)} className="button-success">Save</button>
                        </div>
                        )
                }
                render () {
                    if (this.state.editing) {
                        return this.renderForm();
                    } else {
                        return this.renderNormal();
                    }
                }
            }

            class Manage extends React.Component {
                constructor (props) {
                    super(props);
                    this.removeComment = this.removeComment.bind(this);
                    this.upComment = this.upComment.bind(this);
                    this.state = {
                        comments: [
                            'This is a first comment',
                            'Hi there!',
                            'I am learning React'
                        ]
                    }
                }

                removeComment(i) {
                    console.log(i);
                    var arr = this.state.comments;
                    arr.splice(i, 1);
                    this.setState({comments: arr})
                }

                updateComment(newText, i) {
                    console.log('Updating Comment');
                    var arr = this.state.comments; 
                    arr[i] = newText;
                    this.setState({comments: arr})
                }

                render () {
                    return (
                        <div className="board">
                            {this.state.comments.map(function (text,i) {
                                return (<Basics key={i} index={i} upComment={this.updateComment} delComment={this.removeComment}>
                                            {text}
                                        </Basics>)    
                            }  
                            )}
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            };

            ReactDOM.render(<Manage />, document.getElementById('example'));
        </script>  
        <div id="example"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple errors in your code that needed solving.

1. The bind error is because `upComment` does not exist in your code. What you should bind is the function itself (`updateComment`) and not the prop name.
2. If you are using `this` variable inside any function, it needs to be bound. This is the case in `renderNormal` and `renderForm`.
3. When you are using `this` inside the render function of Manage, you were using an anonymous callback. But then `this` would bind to this callback rather than the class function. Changing this to a arrow function works.

```js
class Basics extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { editing: false };
    this.renderNormal = this.renderNormal.bind(this);
    this.renderForm = this.renderForm.bind(this);
  }
  edit() {
    this.setState({ editing: true });
  }
  save() {
    this.setState({ editing: false });
    this.props.upComment(this.refs.newText.value, this.props.index);
  }
  remove() {
    this.props.delComment(this.props.index);
  }
  renderNormal() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="commentText">{this.props.children}</div>
        <button onClick={this.edit.bind(this)} className="button-primary">Edit</button>
        <button onClick={this.remove.bind(this)} className="button-danger">Remove</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  renderForm() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea ref='newText' defaultValue={this.props.children}></textarea>
        <button onClick={this.save.bind(this)} className="button-success">Save</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.editing) {
      return this.renderForm();
    } else {
      return this.renderNormal();
    }
  }
}

class Manage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.removeComment = this.removeComment.bind(this);
    this.updateComment = this.updateComment.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      comments: [
        'This is a first comment',
        'Hi there!',
        'I am learning React'
      ]
    }
  }

  removeComment(i) {
    console.log(i);
    var arr = this.state.comments;
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({ comments: arr })
  }

  updateComment(newText, i) {
    var arr = this.state.comments;
    arr[i] = newText;
    this.setState({ comments: arr })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="board">
        {this.state.comments.map((text, i)=> {
          return (
          <Basics key={i} index={i} upComment={this.updateComment} delComment={this.removeComment}>
            {text}
          </Basics>)
        }
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Manage />, document.getElementById("example"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the last point of arrow function how it helps and what's need for it, I thought that arrow function is only use for making your function shorter.

Comment: If you are using normal functions, use of `this` inside the function would start to point to the function itself instead of pointing to the class like you want. Arrow functions do not bind `this`. You can read about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this

Comment: Are you referring "map()" to an anonymous function here?

Comment: `function (text,i){}` is anonymous, but still a function that makes `this` inside the same refer to itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your function name is `updateComment` while defining the function but when you're binding the context of the class to the function, the name you're using is `upComment` (class `Manage`, 3rd line in it's `constructor`) which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please accept it @naveen dharni :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to bind methods/functions in the constructor instead do this

```
return (
   <Basics key={i} 
   index={i} 
   upComment={()=>this.updateComment()} 
   delComment={()=>this.removeComment()}>
       {text}
   </Basics>)
```

While assigning the props wrap your functions into anonymous functions it may help i didn't try this.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that `.bind()` call at global attribute event would result in `function () { [native code] }` instead of the function call, and `this` is the global object, for example `window`.

One approach would be to define `edit` and  `remove` as `static` methods and use the `class` as a reference

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {}
  static edit() { console.log("edit") }
  renderNormal() {
    const button = `<div onclick="Test.edit()">click</div>`;
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", button);
  }
}

new Test().renderNormal()
```